# Hibernate: @OrderColumn, re-insert with additions and deletions

Tags: java, hibernate

How am I supposed to update by re-ordering (with additions and deletions) a list and save it back to the DB with Hibernate @OneToMany and @OrderColumn?

The documentation is silent on this question and the only solution I found seems to me lame.

Here is a DB fragment:[image]

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="channel")
public class Channel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="channel_id")
    private Long channelId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderColumn(name = "sequence_order")
    private List<Programme> programmes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addProgramme(Programme programme) {
        programmes.add(programme);
        programme.setChannel(this);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="programme")
public class Programme {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="prog_id")
    private Long progId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name="sequence_order")
    private int order;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="channel_id")
    private Channel channel;
}
```

I am using Spring Data JpaRepositories for basic operations.
Now, I am populating some data which works fine:

```
   @Test
    public void saveTest() {
        Channel channel = new Channel();
        channel.setName("France24");

        Programme programme = new Programme();
        programme.setName("L'enfants show");
        programme.setChannel(channel);
        programme.setType("entertainment");

        Programme programme2 = new Programme();
        programme2.setName("France News");
        programme2.setChannel(channel);
        programme2.setType("news");

        Programme programme3 = new Programme();
        programme3.setName("Holidays in Paris");
        programme3.setChannel(channel);
        programme3.setType("movie");

        Programme programme4 = new Programme();
        programme4.setName("FIFA Cup 2018");
        programme4.setChannel(channel);
        programme4.setType("sport");

        channel.setProgrammes(Arrays.asList(programme, programme2, programme3, programme4));
        channelDao.save(channel);
    }
```

Next come updates with re-ordering and insertions and deletions:

```
// Working solution
@Commit
@Test
public void updateTest() {
    Channel channel = channelDao.findById(1L).get();
    channel.getProgrammes().clear();
    channelDao.flush();

    Programme programme2 = new Programme();
    programme2.setName("France News");
    programme2.setChannel(channel);
    programme2.setType("news");

    Programme programme3 = new Programme();
    programme3.setName("Holidays in Paris");
    programme3.setChannel(channel);
    programme3.setType("movie");

    Programme programme4 = new Programme();
    programme4.setName("FIFA Cup 2018");
    programme4.setChannel(channel);
    programme4.setType("sport");

    Programme programme5 = new Programme();
    programme5.setName("Music show");
    programme5.setChannel(channel);
    programme5.setType("show");

    channel.addProgramme(programme5);
    channel.addProgramme(programme4);
    channel.addProgramme(programme3);
    channel.addProgramme(programme2);
}
```

So, here basically I empty the original list and then re-insert what is left after updates back to the DB in the order I need. Many other attempts to do this update in another way failed.

The question is, can I do it in a **smart way**? Say, delete only what was deleted, update order where it was updated, and insert only what is new?
Sure, I can delete by index and insert at the end of the list, but these basic operations are not enough when it comes to re-ordering the whole list.

Is it possible at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In hibernate, List maintain insert order I mean in your case progId. You could use @OrderBy annotation with order filed. So when fetch Channel it will get Programme and sort by order.

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
            FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("order ASC")
private List<Programme> programmes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: No, progId is not the ordering column in my case, I mean it could a valid case when progId {4, 18, 12, 6, 2, 9}, at the same time sequence_order {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. And the question is not about fetching, but about updating the whole list with reordered elements, plus deletions, plus insertions.